# Laptop keeps killing hard drives, possibly caused by faulty battery

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, power-supply, battery, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS X551M Notebook PC, running Ubuntu 14.04. It's about a year old right now.

When I got it, it worked perfectly. However, a couple months in, the battery started losing lifespan. Eventually, it started happening that if the computer was unplugged, even if the battery was fully charged and showed a lot of time left, the computer would just shut off. It happened sporadically and randomly at first, but then, about 5 months in, it would shut off literally the moment it was unplugged. I basically didn't have a battery from that point on.

This wasn't that big of a deal, but later on, my hard drive failed, evidenced by strange errors such as all my files being marked read-only. I figured it was a freak defect and bought a new hard drive, and reinstalled Ubuntu. This lasted for a few months and then I began to notice the same errors, and sure enough a few days later that hard drive failed too, to the point that I couldn't even get to my home screen.

So a couple days ago I bought a third hard drive, and reinstalled everything. For like two days everything was fine, and then I accidentally unplugged the computer and it immediately shut off. After that I once again couldn't get to my home screen, instead there was just a black screen with a single blinking white cursor. [I asked about this separately.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742875/completely-black-blank-screen-after-boot?noredirect=1)

Finally, I was able to get to my home screen, but I'm getting the same errors I was getting when my other hard drives were about to fail, including that every file is read-only. So I think this hard drive is about to fail too, after about three days of use.

My hunch is that the faulty battery is behind the continuous destruction of the hard drives. I don't know too much about computers, but I made a few google searches for hard drives that keep failing, and one thing that kept coming up was a faulty PSU.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I can do about this? Like I said, I don't know too much about this, so I'm not sure what to look for in terms of signs of faulty hardware in the battery compartment.

Comment: Assuming it wasn't second-hand, you should contact Asus and explain the problem - it's possible they will give you a replacement battery. Warranties don't normally cover wear and tear on batteries but it sounds like your's was faulty all along.

Comment: @James Yeaahhhh the problem is, I think I lost my warranty...there's nothing I can do in that case, right?

Comment: If you have proof of purchase then that would normally be enough but the exact rules would depend on which country you live in.

Comment: @James By proof of purchase, do you mean a reciept?

Comment: Yes, a simple receipt should normally be enough providing it is clear what you bought and where. But it helps if it is from a large retailer that gives a clear invoice including hardware serial numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the battery is acting out of spec and somehow affecting the hard drives, however this is unlikely.

What seems to me to be a lot more likely would be that the system is crashing in a middle of a write, corrupting the data which is being written - this can certainly explain read-inly behaviour (and to fix it, you normally need to do a Checkdisk or disk repair - the read-only behaviour is a signal from the Filesystem that something is wrong with the disk layout, and that further writes before its corrected could result in data corruption).

Comment: So the problem is within the hardware of the computer? Also, how would I perform a Checkdisk/disk repair?

Comment: No, the problem is with it loosing power suddenly in the middle of a write - you can't blame a system for crashing if it does not have power.  I cant exactly answer your question about how to repair the disk because I don't know how it was installed, but the general process would be to boot of another Linux disk (in rescue mode), open up a terminal and type fsck.ext4 /dev/sdXY  (where X is the disk letter and Y is the parition number)

Comment: Sometimes when I boot a screen comes up telling me "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.", and then it gives me the options to (F) fix the errors, (I) ignore, (S) skip mounting, or (M) manual recovery. Is the "(F) fix the errors" option different than what you're talking about?

Comment: Its similar, but not idential. That script is most likely passing the "-p" parameter to fsck.ext4 which will only safely repair some options - unfortunately you need something more drastic.

Comment: Okay. So by another Linux disk, do you mean another hard drive or a boot flashdrive?

Comment: Either. You simply need to have the disk unmounted shen you do the check.

Comment: Could you please walk me through the process? I have a bootable Ubuntu stick.

Comment: Sorry, no.  there are too many variants on the theme, depending on your hardware, level of knowledge etc.  Have a look at https://www.maketecheasier.com/check-repair-filesystem-fsck-linux/    - You may be able to boot a live disk, open a Terminal window and type "fsck -ARy" - but that depends on how your boot disk sees the filesystems.